# Animating along path with anime.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path, anime.js

I'm trying to animate square1 along a spiral path. First I tried loading an svg with an embed tag but was unable to get it to work, so I defined the path directly but still nothing.

I want the square to move to the beginning of the path and then follow the spiral. What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/SquanchyHappy/pen/rNmKJdJ

```
<div id="square1"></div>
<div id="square1"></div>
<svg version="1.1" id="spiral" class="spiral" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 4;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
  </style>
  <path class="st0" d="M477.27,544.55c25.12,0,45.45-20.33,45.45-45.45c0-25.12-20.33-45.45-45.45-45.45
    c-50.25,0-90.91,40.66-90.91,90.91s40.66,90.91,90.91,90.91c75.37,0,136.36-60.99,136.36-136.36c0-75.37-60.99-136.36-136.36-136.36
    c-100.5,0-181.82,81.32-181.82,181.82s81.32,181.82,181.82,181.82c125.62,0,227.27-101.65,227.27-227.27
    S602.89,271.82,477.27,271.82c-150.75,0-272.73,121.98-272.73,272.73s121.98,272.73,272.73,272.73
    c175.87,0,318.18-142.31,318.18-318.18S653.14,180.91,477.27,180.91c-200.99,0-363.64,162.64-363.64,363.64
    s162.64,363.64,363.64,363.64c226.12,0,409.09-182.97,409.09-409.09S703.39,90,477.27,90C226.03,90,22.73,293.3,22.73,544.55
    s203.3,454.55,454.55,454.55c276.37,0,500-223.63,500-500s-223.63-500-500-500" />
</svg>
```

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#square1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: white;
height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#spiral {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: brown;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```
let tl = anime.timeline({ autoplay: false });
let path = anime.path('#spiral');
let squareToCenter = anime({
  targets: '#square1',
  translateX: path('#spiral'),
  translateY: path('#spiral'),
  duration: 5000,
  delay: 1000
});
tl.add(squareToCenter);
tl.play();
```

Comment: When I try to run your code the console says **TypeError: path.el.getPointAtLength is not a function** I used **anime.2.1.0.js**. Then I canged to another version and I receive this one **TypeError: anime.timeline is not a function** What version of anime are you using and where did you got your piece of js used above?

Comment: @SIMBIOSISsurl you can check the codepen's settings, he's using 3.2.1, the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You use `anime.path()` to create a function that'll access path properties. When you call `path()` (note: not `anime.path()` later in your animation's properties, you need to tell it which property you want:

```js
let path = anime.path('#spiral');
let squareToCenter = anime({
  targets: '#square1',
  translateX: path('x'),
  translateY: path('y'),
  duration: 5000,
  delay: 1000
});
```

You're also creating an animation, then adding to a timeline. I don't believe that works. You should use add() directly to add the animation to the timeline. Your timeline might not autoplay, but your animation has no idea about that when it's born into the world.